# Design responsive applications using flutter?

Tags: flutter

what do i have to learn to design responsive applications using flutter? because I have trouble making responsive application designs, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is used to generate one code base that can serve both iOS and Android applications. The word responsive applies to web applications and means they change size depending on the device they are been served to.

If you want to write an application in Flutter you would need to learn Dart. H[ere is a good resource.](https://www.udemy.com/course/dart-flutter-course/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=udemyads&utm_campaign=LongTail_la.EN_cc.UK&utm_content=deal4584&utm_term=_._ag_74409313817_._ad_375954070517_._kw__._de_c_._dm__._pl__._ti_aud-632926098707%3Adsa-850487049997_._li_1007265_._pd__._&matchtype=b&gclid=Cj0KCQiA1-3yBRCmARIsAN7B4H3hMHZSNwiYA2u8pjYiqPMf6ZKlzjOoG1b0-MqouZptvimIStuaKCAaAovfEALw_wcB)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are very new to Flutter.
Here is my tip to make any application responsive

1. Use a layout builder
2. Write a controller file for ui changes and build only those widget which are changing in responsive
3. Make use of Column and Row along with their properties(They are similar to Flex-Box for HTML and CSS)
4. Make Sure to think before creating any responsive application

Here is my channel link. I have recently started making Flutter videos, you can get some inspiration from there too.
**[SpeedCodez](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsRWZBCQwJG_YLP3Z2XaDVQ)**

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is that you use relative measures, and widgets like `Expanded`, `Flexible`, `MediaQuery`, `FittedBox`... among others more advanced, like studying about `**Constraints**` in Flutter.
Responsiveness widgets will help you a lot, and it won't be so difficult!